# How allow to request my API only by my mobile app?

Tags: ios, api, rest

I have developed an API restful in JSON to retrieve data from my server by a mobile app (iOS).
I want to keep hide my API avoiding someone via a network sniffing tool (like wireshark) could find out it.
On my server how i can allow only http request from my mobile app?
What can i do?

Comment: Keep in mind that anything accessible to a client system (be it an iOS app or a a web app) it can be reverse engineered. You can make it difficult but there are many smart people with too much free time on their hands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use SSL and an API token.

Essentially, your request is going to contain your API token or key as a part of the request payload. You can encrypt the data yourself, using SSL, or both.

On the server, you check that the token matches with what is a valid token.